# Why do pythonistas call the current reference "self" and not "this"?

Tags: python

Python is the language I know the most, and strangely I still don't know why I'm typing "self" and not "this" like in Java or PHP.

I know that Python is older than Java, but I can't figure out where does this come from. Especially since you can use any name instead of "self": the program will work fine.

So where does this convention come from?

Comment: You can use "this" instead of "self" as much as you want. However, that might confuse some syntax highlighters and code inspection tools. Using "self" is just a convention.

Comment: "self" and "this" both has four letters, so no one seems to be better than the other.

Comment: I just wrote it's a convention.

Comment: Where did "this" come from?

Comment: So that when they abuse "self", it's self-abuse.

Comment: I've always been tempted to use "other" just to mess with maintainer's heads :-)

Comment: C doesn't have it at all.  JavaScript and PHP are newer than Python... so why don't they use "self" instead of "this"?

Comment: Because [Guido](http://www.python.org/~guido/) decided to use `self'...

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Smalltalk-80, released by Xerox in 1980, used `self`.  Objective-C (early 1980s) layers Smalltalk features over C, so it uses `self` too.  Modula-3 (1988), Python (late 1980s), and Ruby (mid 1990s) also follow this tradition.

C++, also dating from the early 1980s, chose `this` instead of `self`.  Since Java was designed to be familiar to C/C++ developers, it uses `this` too.

Smalltalk uses the metaphor of objects sending messages to each other, so "self" just indicates that the object is sending a message to itself.

Comment: Object Pascal (both the early Apple and the later Borland flavours, including Delphi) also went with "self".

Comment: Smalltalk and Objective-C both use the metaphor of objects sending messages to each other, so "self" just indicates that the object is sending a message to itself.  (It's always seemed more natural to me to use "self" instead of "this".)

Comment: Not to forget self, the language :)

Comment: Great answer except for conflating C and C++ familiarity when talking about java.  Most people doing OOP in C, such as with [gobject](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/) use `self` specifically to avoid reserved keyword clashes if their code is ever included in a C++ project.

Comment: @Karl: Thanks, didn't know that.  Agree with you about my somewhat confusing last sentence.

Comment: There is a notable difference: "this" is a reserved keyword in C/Java and carries a meaning. "self" is not a reserved keyword in Python.

Answer (score 31):

Check the [history of Python](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/adding-support-for-user-defined-classes.html) for user defined classes:

> Instead, one simply defines a function whose first argument corresponds to the instance, which by convention is named "self." For example:

```
def spam(self,y):
    print self.x, y
```

> This approach resembles something I
>   had seen in Modula-3, which had
>   already provided me with the syntax
>   for import and exception handling.

It's a choice as good as any other.  You might ask why C++, Java, and C# chose "this" just as easily.

Comment: Sorry mate, but really you are just repeating what I said in the question : python uses self, it's a convention. The question is why.

Comment: The quotes and link explain the creator of Python's motivation. It would be difficult to get a better 'why' than that. Duffymo isn't repeating your question - Guido is.

Comment: "...something I had seen in Modula-3..." - it's got more documentation than "Smalltalk because I said so."  I believe the "I" in the history is BDFL Guido.

Comment: Didn't follow the link. My mistake.

Comment: "why C++, Java, and C# chose 'this' " -> C# chose 'this' because it derives from Java. Java chose 'this' because it derives from C++. C++ chose 'this' because... I don't know:-)

Comment: We'll have to ask Stroustrup why he did it that way.  Question is almost 5.5 years old.  How does this add value?

Answer (score 19):

Smalltalk, which predates Java of course.

Comment: Thanks pale, will sleep better tonight.

Comment: Not sure why this answer has 18 upvotes. Any particular reasons? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 19):

With respect to python, there is nothing special about `self`. You can use `this` instead if you wanted:

Here's an example:

```
>>> class A(object):
...    def __init__(this):
...       this.x = 3
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.x
3
```

Although you could name it whatever you want, `self` is the convention for the first argument of a class function. Check out [paragraph 5 of section 9.4](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks) in the python documentation, which says:

> Often, the first argument of a method is called self. This is nothing
>   more than a convention: the name self has absolutely no special
>   meaning to Python. Note, however, that by not following the convention
>   your code may be less readable to other Python programmers, and it is
>   also conceivable that a class browser program might be written that
>   relies upon such a convention.

As for the convention, it started out in Smalltalk, but is also used in Object Pascal, Python, Ruby, and Objective-C. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1080192/624900) has a great explanation.

Comment: Thanks @jterrace, i was not aware that i can use `this` in python also. Also your description is reasonable.

Comment: Merged this answer into previous, largely-identical question - you may want to give it a quick once-over.

Comment: "Your code may be less readable to other Python programmers" but it may be *more readable by all the other C#, C++, and Java programmers*, and it may lighten the load on you, if you must program in C++ and Python.

Comment: Good info, I thought I was forgetting something by not adding/using "self".

Answer (score 8):

Python follows Smalltalk's footsteps in the aspect - self is used in Smalltalk as well. I guess the *real* question should be 'why did Bjarne decide to use `this` in C++'...

Comment: Merged this answer into previous, largely-identical question - you may want to give it a quick once-over.

Answer (score 7):

The primary inspiration was Modula-3, which Guido was introduced to at DEC:

> the Modula-3 final report was being
>   written there at about the same time.
>   What I learned there showed up in
>   Python's exception handling, modules,
>   and the fact that methods explicitly
>   contain “self” in their parameter
>   list.

-- Guido, [Linux Journal Interviews Guido van Rossum](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2959)

Answer (score 6):

I think that since it's explicitly declared it makes more sense seeing an actual argument called "self" rather than "this". From the grammatical point of view at least, "self" is not as context dependent as "this".

I don't know if I made myself clear enough, but anyway this is just a subjective appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

`self` is not a keyword (*).

`self` represents by convention the address of the current object

You can get more info on `self` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained).

Why not `this` ? well it is a convention for a name. You can use `this` for your code if you like it better.

---

(*) This answer has been ported and merged here from a question asking `why 'self' instead of 'this' keyword`. As the clarification in this first line could be useful for others I keep it here.

Comment: Merged this answer into previous, largely-identical question - you may want to give it a quick once-over.