# What is the purpose of the `self` parameter? Why is it needed?

Tags: python, class, oop, self

Consider this example:

```py
class MyClass:
    def func(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

I know that `self` refers to the specific instance of `MyClass`. But why must `func` explicitly include `self` as a parameter? Why do we need to use `self` in the method's code? Some other languages make this implicit, or use special syntax instead.

---

<sub>For a *language-agnostic* consideration of the design decision, see [What is the advantage of having this/self pointer mandatory explicit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910020/).</sub>

<sub>To close *debugging questions* where OP omitted a `self` parameter for a method and got a `TypeError`, use [TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944657) instead. If OP omitted `self.` in the body of the method and got a `NameError`, consider [How can I call a function within a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615648).</sub>

Comment: You may find interesting this essay "Why explicit self has to stay" by Guido van Rossum: http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html

Comment: See also "Why must 'self' be used explicitly in method definitions and calls": http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-must-self-be-used-explicitly-in-method-definitions-and-calls

Comment: "Which i understand, quite easily" ---

Quite subjective, don't you think? What makes `@name` more intuitive than `self.name`? The latter, IMO, is more intuitive.

Comment: Although to play devils advocate its very easy to forget to add an additional argument to each method and have bizarre behavior when you forget which makes it hard for beginners. IMHO I rather be specific about unusual things like static methods then normal behavior like instance methods.

Comment: @santa, it wasnt so much the @name and self.name that i didnt get, it was why every function needed an extra argument. Problem solved now though.

Comment: Except for the Ruby comparison, this is the same ground as [ *How to avoid explicit 'self'?* ](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1984121)  (Because of that difference, I wouldn't close as a dupe, but anyone interested should definitely read both sets of answers.)

Comment: @Piotr - I assume you disable the garbage collector?  It's better to explicitly manage memory than to have some garbage collector going around implicitly freeing memory all the time.

Comment: That's the key difference between a function and a class method. A function is floating free, unencumbered. A class (instance) method has to be aware of it's parent (and parent properties) so you need to pass the method a reference to the parent class (as **self**). It's just one less implicit rule that you have to internalize before understanding OOP. Other languages choose syntactic sugar over semantic simplicity, python isn't other languages.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus "explicit is better than implicit" is rule 2 of the Zen of Python; rule 1 is "beautiful is better than ugly" which argues for omitting self.

Comment: @I.J.Kennedy: Not really, no. Sigils or implicit scopes are way more ugly. Not that implicitness with no sigil would work, anyway, in the presence of class attributes and no static verification.

Comment: Well, you never 'pass', `self`. You would call the method like `getUserType()`. If you needed another parameter, yes, you would need to define the method to take another parameter.

Comment: Yuck, self.  Why doesn't the compiler just handle it and make self a keyword?  It's not that bad since it's already in many programming languages as 'this' or something similar.  In all my experience, too much of something is bad for you.  Too much candy, too much water, and too many explicit calls.  Explicit is only > Implicit when explicit is more handy.  If we're going to make self explicit, why not make the entire language explicit and have the users write and compile it themselves?

Comment: See also: [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](/q/17534345/).

Answer (score 795, accepted):

The reason you need to use `self.` is because Python does not use special syntax to refer to instance attributes. Python decided to do methods in a way that makes the instance to which the method belongs be *passed* automatically, but not *received* automatically: the first parameter of methods is the instance the method is called on. That makes methods entirely the same as functions, and leaves the actual name to use up to you (although `self` is the convention, and people will generally frown at you when you use something else.) `self` is not special to the code, it's just another object.

Python could have done something else to distinguish normal names from attributes -- special syntax like Ruby has, or requiring declarations like C++ and Java do, or perhaps something  yet more different -- but it didn't. Python's all for making things explicit, making it obvious what's what, and although it doesn't do it entirely everywhere, it does do it for instance attributes. That's why assigning to an instance attribute needs to know what instance to assign to, and that's why it needs `self.`.

Comment: There is the exception of using *cls* instead of *self*, for example when using the *@classmethod* decorator.

Comment: @Georg: `cls` refers to the class object, not instance object

Comment: The exception is when it's not a "regular" method, or "instance method", but something else -- a classmethod or a staticmethod or just a plain function :)

Comment: @SilentGhost: Actually, the name of the first parameter is whatever you want it to be.  On class methods, the convention is to use `cls` and `self` is used conventionally for instance methods.  If I wanted, I could use `self` for classmethods and `cls` for instance methods. I could also use `bob` and `fnord` if I liked.

Comment: I find it interesting that the community didn't choose `this` instead of `self`. Does `self` have some history that I'm not aware of in older programming languages?

Comment: @Julius The `self` came from Modula-3's conventions, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652006/why-accessing-to-class-variable-from-within-the-class-needs-self-in-python/13652256#13652256) for further details on this choice. (Disclaimer: its mine).

Comment: @ThomasWouters - Is it correct to say that "self" keyword of python is EXACTLY the same as the "this" keyword of Java ? If not, what are the differences ?

Comment: @Julius The `self` keyword (Smalltalk, 1980) predates the `this` keyword (from C++). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079983/why-do-pythonistas-call-the-current-reference-self-and-not-this/1080192#1080192

Comment: It would be nice if self was given to us behind the scenes like Lua and C++ (this) does. " Python's all for making things explicit, making it obvious what's what, and although it doesn't do it entirely everywhere, it does do it for instance attributes." Good thing you ended it that way because coming from other languages I was about to argue the first part of that. Using white space for meaning is NOT an explicit thing at all and it's at the core of python. I'd argue compared to other languages Python isn't very explicit at all. So why stop with explicitly declaring self is the question.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks _Often, the first argument of a method is called `self`. This is nothing more than a convention: the name self has absolutely no special meaning to Python._

Comment: I think that this statement deserves a bold: the first parameter of methods is the instance the method is called on.

Comment: Python instance methods  look like C# extension methods, where the first parameter refers to the instance, regardless of the name you choose for it. In my opinion, it's ugly and unnecessary, but if I wanted a language which suited all my preferences, I should probably make my own programming language.

Comment: This would be explicit only if method would be call like: o = myClass(); myFunc(o, "name");

Comment: This answer is missing a very important part on the _true_reasons for the explicit `self`, which - as explained here https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod - is that python "methods" are actually just plain functions, so the language needed a way to pass the current instance to the function.

Comment: While I was editing the question (to polish it as much as possible, since this is an important canonical), it wasn't completely clear to me whether the question was originally *also* wondering about the need to write `self.` in the code of the function, or *only* about the need to include a `self` parameter. (It might sound strange to suppose that one doesn't follow from the other; but I've seen many questions where OP wrote a `self` parameter but then didn't expect to need to use it). Since this answer is *specifically about* the `self.` usage, and *was accepted by OP*, I feel better now.

Answer (score 630):

Let's say you have a class `ClassA` which contains a method `methodA` defined as:

```
class ClassA:
    def methodA(self, arg1, arg2):
        ... # do something
```

and `objectA` is an instance of this class.

Now when `objectA.methodA(arg1, arg2)` is called, python internally converts it for you as:

```
ClassA.methodA(objectA, arg1, arg2)
```

The `self` variable refers to the object itself.

Comment: I read all the other answers and sort of understood, I read this one and then it all made sense.

Comment: Why not keep those guts inside, though, like Ruby does?

Comment: But in __init__(self) method, it accepts self, then even without creating the object, how does it refer to itself?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though. The OP was asking about why `self` has to be explicitly defined.

Comment: Why then a new function is generated for every instance of `classA`? It seems from this internal conversion that is more appropriate to say that `methodA` is method of the class and not of the instance.

Comment: @saurav `__init__` doesn't create the object; it *initializes* the object by determining its initial state. When you call `MyClass()`, there are several steps behind the scenes. In normal cases: `MyClass.__call__` is looked up and found in `type` (the usual metaclass for classes); that is called, which will call `MyClass.__new__` and **then** pass the result as `self` to `MyClass.__init__`. Meanwhile, `MyClass.__new__` usually defaults to `object.__new__`, which creates a new object of the specified class (i.e., sets its `__class__` and gives it an empty `__dict__` to hold attributes).

Answer (score 442):

Let’s take a simple vector class:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

We want to have a method which calculates the length. What would it look like if we wanted to define it inside the class?

```
    def length(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)
```

What should it look like when we were to define it as a global method/function?

```
def length_global(vector):
    return math.sqrt(vector.x ** 2 + vector.y ** 2)
```

So the whole structure stays the same. How can me make use of this? If we assume for a moment that we hadn’t written a `length` method for our `Vector` class, we could do this:

```
Vector.length_new = length_global
v = Vector(3, 4)
print(v.length_new()) # 5.0
```

This works because the first parameter of `length_global`, can be re-used as the `self` parameter in `length_new`. This would not be possible without an explicit `self`.

---

Another way of understanding the need for the explicit `self` is to see where Python adds some syntactical sugar. When you keep in mind, that basically, a call like

```
v_instance.length()
```

is internally transformed to

```
Vector.length(v_instance)
```

it is easy to see where the `self` fits in. You don't actually write instance methods in Python; what you write is class methods which must take an instance as a first parameter. And therefore, you’ll have to place the instance parameter somewhere explicitly.

Comment: Vector.length_new = length_global... I actually started to use syntax like this in my class declarations. Whenever I only want to inherit some of the methods from another class, I just explicitly copy the reference to the methods.

Comment: would it be fair to say that python's "instance method" is simply a syntactic sugar of static global methods (as in Java or C++) with an instance object passed in to package multiple attributes?  --- well this is kind of half-true since in polymorphism, the more important purpose of "this" (as in java) or "self" is to give u the correct implementation of methods. Python does have this. so calling myobj.someMethod() is equal to TheClassOfMyObj.someMethod(myobj) in python. note that the "TheClassOfMyObj" is automatically figured out by python from "self", otherwise u'd have to find that out.

Comment: Infact, not only are instance methods just class methods, but methods are just functions which are members of a class, as the `Vector.length_new = length_global` shows.

Comment: "This works, because the first parameter of length_global, can be re-used as the self parameter in length_new. This would not be possible without an explicit self." - it would work just the same. it would be re-used for the implicit self... the second example is a circular reasoning - you have to explicitly place self there, because python needs the explicit self.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Sure, it would also be possible to have a language with a model where internally defined methods do not need an explicit self but externally defined methods do. But I’d say there is some consistency in requiring the explicit self in both cases, which makes it a legitimate reason to do it this way. Other languages may choose different approaches.

Comment: So, with Ruby, would refactoring between a function and a method require searching for each of the `@variables` and removing the `@` sign? (Great answer, thanks!)

Comment: I think that even more technically, `v_instance.length()` is transformed to `Vector.length.__get__(v_instance, Vector)()`, but that might make the waters a little more muddy than we want them ;-)

Comment: @mgilson: Or even something like `type(v_instance)` instead of `Vector` before that.

Comment: "You don't actually write instance methods in Python; what you write is class methods which (must) take an instance as a first parameter. And therefore, you’ll have to place the instance parameter somewhere explicitly." *This* explained it more clearly than the text directly above.

Answer (score 253):

When objects are instantiated, the object itself is passed into the `self` parameter.

[image]

Because of this, the object’s data *is bound to the object*. Below is an example of how one might like to visualize what each object’s data might look. Notice how `self` is replaced with the object's name. I'm not saying this example diagram below is wholly accurate, but it will hopefully help one visualize the use of `self`.

[image]

The Object is passed into the `self` parameter so that the object can keep hold of its own data.

Although this may not be wholly accurate, think of the process of instantiating (creating *and* assigning internal values) an object like this: When an object is made, the object uses the class as a template for its (the object's) own data and methods. Without passing the object's own variable name into the `self` parameter, the attributes and methods in the class would remain a general template and would not be referenced to (belong to) the object. So, by passing the object's name into the `self` parameter, it means that if 100 objects are instantiated from the one class, each of the 100 objects can keep track of its (each object's) own data and methods.

Summary: Classes are general (not ultra-specific) templates that a newly created object can pass its own specific data into (without *necessarily* affecting the rest of the objects that could be created from the same class), allowing for less copy-pasted code that serves the purpose of creating many objects that have the same patterns. `self` is for specifying that a *specific object*'s data should be used instead of some other data.

See the illustration below:

[image]

Comment: Hey there, when accessing Bob's attributes for example by "bob.name()", you actually accesing bob().self.name so to speak from the '__init__' right?

Comment: When you write bob.name() in the above comment, you are implying that bob has a method called name() due to the fact that you added brackets after name. In this example however there is no such method. 'bob.name' (which has no parenthesis) is directly accessing the attribute called name from the init (constructor) method. When bob's speak method is called it is the method which accesses the name attribute and returns it in a print statement. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah without paranthesis i wanted to write sry. So the value of name you actually get it and not of self.name because as far as i know self.name and name are 2 different variable. Thanks

Comment: No, you get the value of self.name, which for the bob object is actually bob.name, because the object's name is passed into the self parameter when it is created (instantiated). Again, hope this helps. Feel free to upvote main post if it has.

Comment: Name is assigned to self.name at instantiation. After an object is created, all variables that belong to the object are those prefixed with 'self.' Remember that self is replaced with the object's name when it is created from the class.

Comment: Very clear explanation. But, how to validate its correctness?

Comment: What happens if I don't use self but just age, sex, name...?

Comment: What an awesome answer - thanks for taking the time to put it on here.

Answer (score 88):

I like this example:

```py
class A: 
    foo = []

a, b = A(), A()
a.foo.append(5)

b.foo  # [5]
```

```
class A: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.foo = []

a, b = A(), A()
a.foo.append(5)

b.foo  # []
```

Comment: so vars without self is simply static vars of the class, like in java

Comment: teddy teddy, you aren't entirely correct. The behavior (static or non-static like) depends not only on `self` but also on the variable type. Try to do the first example with simple integer instead of list. The result would be quite different.

Comment: Actually, my question with this is why are you allowed to say `a.foo` in the first example, rather than `A.foo`? Clearly `foo` belongs to the class...

Comment: You can call static members from instances of the object in most languages. Why is that surprising?

Comment: @RadonRosborough Because in the first example, `a` and `b` are both labels (or pointers)  for `A()` (the class). `a.foo` references the `A().foo` class method.  In the second example, though, `a` becomes a reference to an *instance* of `A()`, as does `b`.  Now that they are instances instead of the class object itself, *self* allows the `foo` method to operate on the instances.

Comment: @LegendaryDude This is not entirely true, in *both* cases, `a` and `b` are *references to instances* of `A()`, however, in the second case, `a.foo` and `b.foo` refer to a reference inside *themselves*, whereas in the first case, `a.foo` and `b.foo` refer to a reference inside the *class*. The reason you can access references inside the *class* is for simplicity (as is so often the case in Python): Imagine a function `def bar(self): return self.foo;`. Since we can reference class members, `f = a.bar; f(a);` will do the exact same as `f = A.bar; f(a)`, and `f` will be the same in both cases.

Answer (score 47):

I will demonstrate with code that **does not use classes**:

```
def state_init(state):
    state['field'] = 'init'

def state_add(state, x):
    state['field'] += x

def state_mult(state, x):
    state['field'] *= x

def state_getField(state):
    return state['field']

myself = {}
state_init(myself)
state_add(myself, 'added')
state_mult(myself, 2)

print( state_getField(myself) )
#--> 'initaddedinitadded'
```

Classes are just a way to avoid passing in this "state" thing all the time (and other nice things like initializing, class composition, the rarely-needed metaclasses, and supporting custom methods to override operators).

Now let's demonstrate the above code using the built-in python class machinery, to show how it's basically the same thing.

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.field = 'init'
    def add(self, x):
        self.field += x
    def mult(self, x):
        self.field *= x

s = State()
s.add('added')    # self is implicitly passed in
s.mult(2)         # self is implicitly passed in
print( s.field )
```

[migrated my answer from duplicate closed question]

Comment: I wish Python sugarcoated the handlers as well as Ruby does.

Comment: What if I don't use self, I just use  field += x ?

Answer (score 22):

The following excerpts are from the [Python documentation about self](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html):

> As in Modula-3, there are no shorthands [in Python] for referencing the object’s members from its methods: the method function is declared with an explicit first argument representing the object, which is provided implicitly by the call.
>
> Often, the first argument of a method is called self. This is nothing more than a convention: the name self has absolutely no special meaning to Python. Note, however, that by not following the convention your code may be less readable to other Python programmers, and it is also conceivable that a class browser program might be written that relies upon such a convention.

For more information, see the [Python documentation tutorial on classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 22):

As well as all the other reasons already stated, it allows for easier access to overridden methods; you can call `Class.some_method(inst)`.

An example of where it’s useful:

```
class C1(object):
    def __init__(self):
         print "C1 init"

class C2(C1):
    def __init__(self): #overrides C1.__init__
        print "C2 init"
        C1.__init__(self) #but we still want C1 to init the class too
```

```
>>> C2()
"C2 init"
"C1 init"
```

Answer (score 18):

Its use is similar to the use of `this` keyword in Java, i.e. to give a reference to the current object.

Comment: class myClass:
        def myFunc(this, name):
            this.name = name

Answer (score 13):

Python is not a language built for Object Oriented Programming, unlike Java or C++.

First off, methods belong to either an entire class (*static method*) or an object (instance) of the class (*object method*).

When calling a static method in Python, one simply writes a method with regular arguments inside it.

```
class Animal():
    def staticMethod():
        print "This is a static method"
```

However, an object (i.e., instance) method, which requires you to make an object (i.e. instance, an Animal in this case), needs the `self` argument.

```
class Animal():
    def objectMethod(self):
        print "This is an object method which needs an instance of a class"
```

The `self` method is also used to refer to a variable field within the class.

```
class Animal():
    #animalName made in constructor
    def Animal(self):
        self.animalName = "";

    def getAnimalName(self):
        return self.animalName
```

In this case, `self` is referring to the animalName variable of the *entire class*. REMEMBER: If you have a new variable *created* within a method (called a local variable), `self` will not work. That variable exists only while that method is running. For defining fields (the variables of the entire class), you have to define them OUTSIDE the class methods.

If you don't understand a single word of what I am saying, then Google "Object Oriented Programming." Once you understand this, you won't even need to ask that question :).

Comment: +1 because of the distinction between `staticMethod()` and `objectMethod(self)`. I would like to add that in order to invoke the first, you would say `Animal.staticMethod()`, while `objectMethod()` needs an instance: `a = Animal(); a.objectMethod()`

Comment: What you are saying isn't 100% true. That's just a convention. You can still call the static method from an object created. You just won't be able to use any class members because you didn't declare a self. I can even call Animal.objectMethod(animalObj) to call the non static. Basically this means a static method is only a method that doesn't use member variables. There shouldn't be any need to declare self. It's a silly language requirement I think. Languages like Lua and C++ give you obj variables behind the scenes.

Comment: You made a useless animalName string declaration and crashing animalName method.

Comment: To @user441521, python is meant for scripting not oop , it does not excel in oop standards. To timmerman, this was written for educational purpose, its a minor error, only those who simply copy paste without understanding, which SO finds unethical, will have problems with the answer.

Comment: @ytpillai Irrelevant. Confusing and incorrect code should not be presented as an answer.

Comment: Fixed the question

Comment: `def getAnimalName` to not clobber the string you're trying to return, and `self` refers to the instance of the class, not any field inside of it.

Comment: _For defining fields (the variables of the entire class), you have to define them OUTSIDE the class methods._ ... The differentiation between _class attributes_ and _instance attributes_ is very vague - you can create instance attributes just fine inside instance methods - creating class attributes also works if you prefix them witht the classes name ... `Animal.ClawDamage = 200` inside `def getAnimalName(self):` works just fine -any Animal will have that attribute

Answer (score 13):

First of all, self is a conventional name, you could put anything else (being coherent) in its stead.

It refers to the object itself, so when you are using it, you are declaring that .name and .age are properties of the Student objects (note, not of the Student class) you are going to create.

```
class Student:
    #called each time you create a new Student instance
    def __init__(self,name,age): #special method to initialize
        self.name=name
        self.age=age

    def __str__(self): #special method called for example when you use print
        return "Student %s is %s years old" %(self.name,self.age)

    def call(self, msg): #silly example for custom method
        return ("Hey, %s! "+msg) %self.name

#initializing two instances of the student class
bob=Student("Bob",20)
alice=Student("Alice",19)

#using them
print bob.name
print bob.age
print alice #this one only works if you define the __str__ method
print alice.call("Come here!") #notice you don't put a value for self

#you can modify attributes, like when alice ages
alice.age=20
print alice
```

[Code is here](http://labs.codecademy.com/DJ9z#:workspace)

Answer (score 11):

`self` is an object reference to the object itself, therefore, they are same.
Python methods are not called in the context of the object itself.
`self` in Python may be used to deal with custom object models or something.

Answer (score 11):

It’s there to follow the Python zen “explicit is better than implicit”. It’s indeed a reference to your class object. In Java and PHP, for example, it's called `this`.

If `user_type_name` is a field on your model you access it by `self.user_type_name`.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the following example, which clearly explains the purpose of `self`

```
class Restaurant(object):  
    bankrupt = False

    def open_branch(self):
        if not self.bankrupt:
           print("branch opened")

#create instance1
>>> x = Restaurant()
>>> x.bankrupt
False

#create instance2
>>> y = Restaurant()
>>> y.bankrupt = True   
>>> y.bankrupt
True

>>> x.bankrupt
False
```

`self` is used/needed to distinguish between instances.

Source: [self variable in python explained - Pythontips](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/)

Comment: Yes, I think we know why self is used, but the question is why does the language make you explicitly declare it. Many other languages don't require this and a language which prides itself on being brief, you'd think they would just give you the variable behind the scenes to use like Lua or C++ (this) does.

Comment: @kmario23 You're response was from here: https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/

Please always acknowledge original authors when posting answers as your own.

Answer (score 8):

I'm surprised nobody has brought up Lua. Lua also uses the 'self' variable however it can be omitted but still used. C++ does the same with 'this'. I don't see any reason to have to declare 'self' in each function but you should still be able to use it just like you can with lua and C++. For a language that prides itself on being brief it's odd that it requires you to declare the self variable.

Answer (score 8):

The use of the argument, conventionally called `self` isn't as hard to understand, as is why is it necessary? Or as to why explicitly mention it? That, I suppose, is a bigger question for most users who look up this question, or if it is not, they will certainly have the same question as they move forward learning python. I recommend them to read these couple of blogs:

[1: Use of self explained](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/)

Note that it is not a keyword.

> The first argument of every class method, including init, is always a reference to the current instance of the class. By convention, this argument is always named self. In the init method, self refers to the newly created object; in other class methods, it refers to the instance whose method was called. For example the below code is the same as the above code.

[2: Why do we have it this way and why can we not eliminate it as an argument, like Java, and have a keyword instead](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html)

Another thing I would like to add is, an optional `self` argument allows me to declare static methods inside a class, by not writing `self`.

Code examples:

```
class MyClass():
    def staticMethod():
        print "This is a static method"

    def objectMethod(self):
        print "This is an object method which needs an instance of a class, and that is what self refers to"
```

**PS**:This works only in Python 3.x.

In previous versions, you have to explicitly add `@staticmethod` decorator, otherwise `self` argument is obligatory.

Answer (score 5):

Is because by the way python is designed the alternatives would hardly work. Python is designed to allow methods or functions to be defined in a context where both implicit `this` (a-la Java/C++) or explicit `@` (a-la ruby) wouldn't work. Let's have an example with the explicit approach with python conventions:

```
def fubar(x):
    self.x = x

class C:
    frob = fubar
```

Now the `fubar` function wouldn't work since it would assume that `self` is a global variable (and in `frob` as well). The alternative would be to execute method's with a replaced global scope (where `self` is the object).

The implicit approach would be

```
def fubar(x)
    myX = x

class C:
    frob = fubar
```

This would mean that `myX` would be interpreted as a local variable in `fubar` (and in `frob` as well). The alternative here would be to execute methods with a replaced local scope which is retained between calls, but that would remove the posibility of method local variables.

However the current situation works out well:

```
 def fubar(self, x)
     self.x = x

 class C:
     frob = fubar
```

here when called as a method `frob` will receive the object on which it's called via the `self` parameter, and `fubar` can still be called with an object as parameter and work the same (it *is* the same as `C.frob` I think).

Answer (score 3):

In the `__init__` method, self refers to the newly created object; in other class methods, it refers to the instance whose method was called.

self, as a name, is ***just a convention***, call it as you want ! but when using it, for example to delete the object, you have to use the same name: `__del__(var)`, where `var` was used in the `__init__(var,[...])`

You should take a look at `cls` too, to have ***the bigger picture***. This [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554738/python-self-no-self-and-cls) could be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

self is acting as like current object name or instance of class .

```
# Self explanation.


 class classname(object):

    def __init__(self,name):

        self.name=name
        # Self is acting as a replacement of object name.
        #self.name=object1.name

   def display(self):
      print("Name of the person is :",self.name)
      print("object name:",object1.name)


 object1=classname("Bucky")
 object2=classname("ford")

 object1.display()
 object2.display()

###### Output 
Name of the person is : Bucky
object name: Bucky
Name of the person is : ford
object name: Bucky
```

Answer (score 2):

"self" keyword holds the reference of class and it is upto you if you want to use it or not but if you notice, whenever you create a new method in python, python automatically write self keyword for you. If you do some R&D, you will notice that if you create say two methods in a class and try to call one inside another, it does not recognize method unless you add self (reference of class).

```
class testA:
def __init__(self):
    print('ads')
def m1(self):
    print('method 1')
    self.m2()
def m2(self):
    print('method 2')
```

Below code throws unresolvable reference error.

```
class testA:
def __init__(self):
    print('ads')
def m1(self):
    print('method 1')
    m2()  #throws unresolvable reference error as class does not know if m2 exist in class scope
def m2(self):
    print('method 2')
```

Now let see below example

```
class testA:
def __init__(self):
    print('ads')
def m1(self):
    print('method 1')
def m2():
    print('method 2')
```

Now when you create object of class testA, you can call method m1() using class object like this as method m1() has included self keyword

```
obj = testA()
obj.m1()
```

But if you want to call method m2(), because is has no self reference so you can call m2() directly using class name like below

```
testA.m2()
```

But keep in practice to live with self keyword as there are other benefits too of it like creating global variable inside and so on.

Answer (score 1):

#### *`self` is inevitable.*

There was just a [question](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=239003) should `self` be implicit or explicit.
[`Guido van Rossum`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum) resolved this question saying [`self` has to stay](https://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html).

#### *So where the `self` live?*

If we would just stick to functional programming we would not need `self`.
Once we enter the *Python OOP* we find `self` there.

Here is the typical use case `class C` with the method `m1`

```
class C:
    def m1(self, arg):
        print(self, ' inside')
        pass

ci =C()
print(ci, ' outside')
ci.m1(None)
print(hex(id(ci))) # hex memory address
```

---

This program will output:

```
<__main__.C object at 0x000002B9D79C6CC0>  outside
<__main__.C object at 0x000002B9D79C6CC0>  inside
0x2b9d79c6cc0
```

So `self` holds the memory address of the class instance.
*The purpose* of `self` would be to hold the reference for *instance methods* and for us to have **explicit** access to that reference.

---

<sub>Note there are three different types of class methods:</sub>

- <sub>static methods (read: functions),</sub>
- <sub>class methods,</sub>
- <sub>instance methods (mentioned).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The word 'self' refers to instance of a class

```
class foo:
      def __init__(self, num1, num2):
             self.n1 = num1 #now in this it will make the perimeter num1 and num2 access across the whole class
             self.n2 = num2
      def add(self):
             return self.n1 + self.n2 # if we had not written self then if would throw an error that n1 and n2 is not defined and we have to include self in the function's perimeter to access it's variables
```

Answer (score 0):

it's an explicit reference to the class instance object.

Comment: I don't think this helps richzilla to understand the reason behind it.

Comment: @SilentGhost: you have nailed it. I am impressed. if I understand it correctly: I do create an object as an instance of the defined class and the self parameter refers to that object? I understand self refers in implicit way to the class itself but it would be great if you explain your answer a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects),

> the special thing about methods is that the instance object is passed as the first argument of the function. In our example, the call `x.f()` is exactly equivalent to `MyClass.f(x)`. In general, calling a method with a list of n arguments is equivalent to calling the corresponding function with an argument list that is created by inserting the method’s instance object before the first argument.

preceding this the related snippet,

```
class MyClass:
    """A simple example class"""
    i = 12345

    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'
```

`x = MyClass()`

Answer (score 0):

I would say for Python at least, the self parameter can be thought of as a placeholder.
Take a look at this:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

p1 = Person("John", 36)

print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)
```

Self in this case and a lot of others was used as a method to say store the name value. However, after that, we use the p1 to assign it to the class we're using. Then when we print it we use the same p1 keyword.

Hope this helps for Python!

Answer (score 0):

my little 2 cents

In this class Person, we defined out **init** method with the self and interesting thing to notice here is the memory location of both the **self** and instance variable **p** is same `<__main__.Person object at 0x106a78fd0>`

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name 
        self.age = age 

    def say_hi(self):
        print("the self is at:", self)
        print((f"hey there, my name is {self.name} and I am {self.age} years old"))

    def say_bye(self):
        print("the self is at:", self)
        print(f"good to see you {self.name}")

p = Person("john", 78)
print("the p is at",p)
p.say_hi()  
p.say_bye()
```

so as explained in above, both self and instance variable are same object.