# "self" instead of traditional "this" keyword?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do pythonistas call the current reference “self” and not “this”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079983/why-do-pythonistas-call-the-current-reference-self-and-not-this)

I am wondering why there is in Python the convention to use `self` in classes instead of the traditional `this` keyword. It is used in some other languages so why python came up with `self` keyword??